# Is there an effective way to extract all the names used in a Clojure/ClojureScript for a refactoring (renaming driven) effort?

Tags: clojure, grep, refactoring, batch-rename

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

Usually, I build the project by executing the command `cider-jack-in-cljs` in Emacs, choosing `shadow-cljs`, then `shadow` for REPL type, and, finally, `app` for the building option.

The project has some naming problems. Some names used for functions, variables, and namespaces were not ideal for the domain.

There is a desire to do a refactoring on the code base in order to improve names and conventions.

The Product Manager with domain expertise (but no CS skills) asked for the names so that he could do a review.

My initial idea was doing a bunch of `git greps` using **clojure syntax** to focus on the creation of names associated with variables, functions, or namespaces:

```bash
$ git grep "(ns "
$ git grep "(defn- "
$ git grep "(def "
$ git grep "(defn "
```

But I **am not** sure this is the best approach...

Why is this kind of a Clojure question?

Well, I am new to Clojure, but since Clojure keeps everything in a Lisp image and Lisps, in general, deal with symbols in smart ways (symbolic computation is all about that), I thought that there could be a better way to use Clojure for this.

Also, it can be an Emacs question... Since Emacs is so awesome and powerful, maybe there is some trick from Cider to help with this problem.

Comment: https://github.com/clj-commons/rewrite-clj along with some links in its README.

Comment: After loading all of your project's namespaces (typically this will already be done by the time `-main` starts), you can look through the results of `(all-ns)`. Filter it down to namespaces that start with your project's root, and look at the `(ns-interns)` of those namespaces.